# Is it possible not to add JDBC to classpath?

Tags: java, deployment, jdbc, classpath, desktop-application

Is it possible not to add the JDBC to CLASSPATH? just use the source code.

I am creating a program that connects to the database but I don't want my users asking them to add the JDBC to there classpath it might be too hard for them. is it possible not to add the JDBC to the classpath?

Comment: What type of app. is this?  E.G. Web-App, desktop app., command line app.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

Actually isn't a beautiful approach...

You use a folder called lib and put your odbc jar i there, use the relative path to the lib jar, like 'lib/jodbc.jar'

You can embedded the jar in a folder called resource, after that every time you start your application,  you look for the folder lib/jodbc.jar, if not exist you can create the folder and copy the resource file inside your application to the folder and done.

I use this approach in some applications and worked fine so far. I had the same problem, the difficult for the user add the classpath, so I only use 'portable' jre and libs inside my apps.

Sorry for don't show examples, but I'm in class right now.

If you need more examples, let me know and in Monday I can answer.

Cya.

---

First you need to add the lib in your project.

If you are using NetBeans, go in your Project Properties, in your lib, you add the jar, but first put a folder inside your project folder called lib and with your .jar, then add the jar and select the relative path.

---

To copy a resource:

```
    //Create the /lib directory with the .jars and the service.exe
    //The resource_path is the package where are your files...
    String resource_path = "br/com/myservice/resources/";
    Util.copyResource(this.getClass().getClassLoader(), resource_path, "PAF_Service.exe", currentDirectory);

    resource_path = resource_path + "lib/";
    String directory_lib = currentDirectory + "lib/";

    File dir_lib = new File(directory_lib);
    if(!dir_lib.exists()){
        dir_lib.mkdir();
    }

    Util.copyResource(this.getClass().getClassLoader(), resource_path, "ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.5-jar-with-dependencies.jar", directory_lib);
    Util.copyResource(this.getClass().getClassLoader(), resource_path, "log4j-1.2.17.jar", directory_lib);
    Util.copyResource(this.getClass().getClassLoader(), resource_path, "WinRun4J.jar", directory_lib);
```

---

The copyResource method:

```
    public static boolean copyResource(ClassLoader classLoader, String resource_path, String resource, String destiny){
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    Boolean retorno = false;
    try {
        InputStream is = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(resource_path + resource);

        if(is == null){
            System.out.println("Resource not found! >> " + resource_path + resource);
            retorno = false;
        }

        fos = new FileOutputStream( new File(destiny, resource));
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read = -1;
        while( (read = is.read(buffer)) != -1 ) {
            fos.write( buffer,0,read);
        }
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        retorno = true;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Principal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Principal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        try {
            if(fos != null)
                fos.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Principal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    return retorno;
}
```

Comment: I would really want a example william thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

No, it isn't.  Or more accurately, while it might be possible to add the JDBC jars to the run-time classpath at run-time in a way that is relatively invisible to the user, it is not possible to do JDBC without the relevant driver.

For deploying Java desktop apps., the best option is usually to install the app. using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  JWS works on Windows, OS X & *nix.

That is more effort for you, but a breeze for the end user.  They never need to know anything about the run-time class-path or what is or isn't on it.  You can also give them a convenient desktop shortcut or menu item to launch the app.

Answer (score 1):

It is theoretically possible to write your own JDBC driver.  If you did that, your JDBC driver would be part of *your* codebase and could be in your application's JAR.  But this sounds like a **really bad idea ...**

It is also possible to create an "uber jar" that combines your code and 3rd-party code into a single JAR file.  However there's a catch.  Some open source licenses (e.g. LGPL) don't allow you to do this.  Rather, they can require that code covered by the license is supplied in a form that makes it *easy* for the end user to replace one version of the library with another one.  The "uber jar" approach makes this difficult.

However, the best approach is to package your application as multiple JARs, and arrange that the installer puts the JARs in the right place and uses a wrapper script or custom launcher to ensure that the CLASSPATH is correct.

Or use WebStart as @Andrew Thompson recommends.  That has other advantages too, such as providing an easy way to handle updates, or check that the user's JRE installation is up-to-date.